# jQuery - Each() Selector Works on Other Elements, how to avoid?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-selectors

**What I'm trying to do:**

jQuery checks for all: `<div class="message-body">`

However, another div called: `<div class="message-body">` gets selected as well.

The code works as intended - but is ***including*** other divs with similar names.

How can I prevent jQuery from selecting these other elements?

Example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5HJE/

The top image should NOT work as a link.

The bottom image should be the only one to work as a link.

I'm not experienced in jQuery at all, but I needed this simple function for my site.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: the fiddle you posted have one div with this "message" and the other one "message-body" .

Comment: the problem is i guess with 'img' tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you need to get img tags inside `<div class="message-body">`, so you can modify your javascript code to become:

```
$('.message-body').each(function ()
{
   $(this).find('img').each(function ()
   {
      var currImg = $(this);  // cache the selector
      currImg.wrap("<a target='_blank' href='" + currImg.attr("src") + "'/>");
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does exactly what you told it to do.

when iterating over all `.message-body` elements it should do it over **all** of them.

After noticing you probably mispelled your question, the probem in your case is you iterate through all divs and then you iterate again through all `img` tags,regardless of their position.
You should try this :`$('.message-body img')` in your first `each` loop, you don't need both.

Code :

```
   $('.message-body img').each(function ()
   {
      var currImg = $(this);
      currImg.wrap("<a target='_blank' href='" + currImg.attr("src") + "'/>");
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work :)

```
 $(function ()
    {
       $('.message-body').each(function ()
        {
           $(this).find('img').each(function ()
            {
                var currImg = $(this);  // cache the selector
                currImg.wrap("<a target='_blank' href='" + currImg.attr("src") + "'/>");
            });
        });
    });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z5HJE/2/